# Can the prices of goods be copyrighted?

Tags: copyright, trademark, copyfraud

I am looking to publish a list of prices for which companies are willing to sell certain generic (commodity type) products. These companies have already published their own "price guides" that list the cost of each product in a table format.

I will be taking the cheapest price for each product and incorporating it into my own "master price guide," which I will then publish periodically on our website for paid subscribers to view.

Does the act of re-publishing these prices infringe on the copyright held by the companies who released the information in the first place? I will be publishing the prices in an entirely different format from the company tables where I get them from.

Would these prices be considered facts? Business operations? Or am I infringing on their copyright?

Answer (score 3):

The prices are facts, there is no copyright violation.

Comment: So are technical manuals, but they're still copyrighted.

Comment: @Consis the layout and structure is, the facts aren’t

Comment: @Consis similarly, sports scores are not copyrighted.  A still from the broadcast showing the scores is.

Comment: Technical manuals are not just a listing of bare facts.

Comment: @Consis The specific specifications in the technical manuals are the facts. I.e. it contains facts. But the manual itself is not "a fact" it is assumes to be a creative work that compiles facts.